# How to establish Request/Response mechanism between to asp.net usercontrol pages using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In work environment i came across situation where i have two asp.net pages

Control1 loads Control 2 via iframe and Control2 has some long running activity once user click on start .

1. Now my requirement is once control2 started activity it should send
   acknowledgement to control1.
2. Control1 trying to stop control2 activity control1 has to send info
   to Control2.Then Control2 should perform cleaning up of sessions ans
   send response to control1 then stop long running activity.

Some kind of request response mechanism should happen.

Onstarted:
Eg: Control2 should send response to conrol1 -"Control2 is started"
Control1 :Stop button is cliked:
Eg:Control1 should send message to control2 to "Stop"

Control2 has to send Message (Yes/No)  On Yes control1 should close Control2

All these things should happen with Javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you give us some code examples? it seems quite impossible right now.

Comment: "Some kind of request response mechanism should happen." - everything in a web application happens through request/response mechanism. The description of your problem is not good. Try again.